Computation of $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-b)^2}{x}}}{x^k}\text{d}x$
I struggle to compute the integral $I$ defined as follow:
$$I := \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-b)^2}{x}}}{x^k}\text{d}x$$
with $b>0$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$.
Integral $I$ is well defined
First of all, this integral is finite. As $x\to 0$, the integrand tends to 0. As $x\to+\infty$, the integrand is smaller than the function $\exp(-x)$ that is clearly integrable. We have then $I<\infty$.
What I have thought about
This kind of integral is generally solved by integration by part and applying a recursion. In this case, I can't see any antiderivatives that could make this method doable.
Any hints, references or solutions will be highly appreciated!
Thank you in advance.

WolframAlpha says the integral is equal to:
$$
I = 2\cdot e^{2b} b^{1-k} \mathbf{K}{k-1}(2b)
$$
where $\mathbf{K}{n}(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Thank you @EgorLarionov for your answer. I have already consulted WolframAlpha but I can't find any properties that relates Modified Bessel function of second kind with my integral...

The substitution $x = b \exp t$ looks like a promising way to rewrite the integral using the integral representation $K_\alpha(x) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-x \cosh t) \cosh \alpha t ,dt$.

Let $x=1/\sqrt{u}$ and later $u=v/b^2$, then your integral becomes
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty u^{\frac{k-3}2} \exp\left(-\frac1{\sqrt{u}}+2b-
b^2\sqrt{u}\right)du=e^{2b}\int_0^\infty u^{\frac{k-3}2} \exp\left(-\frac1{\sqrt{u}}-b^2\sqrt{u}\right)du
\\&=\frac{e^{2b}}{b^{k-1}}\int_0^\infty v^{\frac{k-3}2} \exp\left(-\frac{b}{\sqrt{v}}-b\sqrt{v}\right)dv=
\frac{e^{2b}}{b^{k-1}}\int_0^\infty v^{\frac{k-3}2} \exp\left(-\frac{b}{\sqrt{v}}-b\sqrt{v}\right)dv=
%
\\ &=\frac{e^{2b}}{b^{k-1}}\int_0^\infty b^{k-1} t^{-k} \exp\left(-t-\frac{b^2}t\right)dv
%
\\ &= \frac{e^{2b}}{b^{k-1}}\cdot 2 \mathrm{BesselK}(k-1,2b)
\end{align}
with $v=b^2/t^2$.

Thank you van der Wolf ! Can you tell me from which definition you get the last equaility ?

@NancyBoy please se https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32  , formula 10.32.10

Most likely this won't be of much help, I'll tell you why later, but at least it's something.
So let's integrate by parts the integral given. One obtains:
$$
I_{k} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\frac{-(x-b)^2}{x}}{x^{-k}} = \\
\underbrace{-\frac{1}{k-1}\exp{\left(-\frac{(x-b)^2}{x}\right)}
{x^{-k+1}}\Bigg|_{0}^{\infty}}_{\text{equals to 0}}+
\frac{1}{k-1}\int_{0}^{\infty} \exp{\left(-\frac{(x-b)^2}{x}\right)}
{x^{-k+1}} \cdot \frac{b^2-x^2}{x^2} = \\
\frac{1}{k-1}\left( b^2I_{k+1}-I_{k-1}\right)
$$
Rearranging the terms yields:
$$
I_{k+1} = \frac{1}{b^2} \big( (k-1)I_{k}+I_{k-1}\big)
$$
Technically, one could compose a characteristic equation for this recurrenсе formula and calcuate the generating function. The problem is (I promised) is that you need to know the first couple of values for $I_1$ and $I_2$ to calculate the general solution. Whereas usually they are quite calculable $-$ say, Fibonacci series or a tridiagonal matrix $-$ in this case it's hardly so.

Thank you very much for your insights !
